# Django, при изменение данных, он создает новый, как иcпраить? что бы он не создовал, а изменял текущий

Tags: sql, python-3.x, django

вот вьюха

```
def detail_edit(request, id):
    if request.user.username == 'admin':
        item = get_object_or_404(Buses, id=id)
        form = ItemForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES, instance=item, )
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('index')
            return redirect('index')
        return render(request, 'buses/detail_edit.html', {'form': form, 'bus': item})
    return redirect('index')
```

detail_edit.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expend-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">ТрансМашХолдинг - ОШ</a>
                <a href="{% url 'detail' bus.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-mob"><i
                        class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-left"></i> Назад</a>
                <div class="text-white">Admin</div>
                <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-mob"><i class="fas fa-door-open"></i>
                    Выйти</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form action="{% url 'detail_edit' bus.id %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ bus.photo_person.url }}" alt="">
                                <br>
                                {{ form.photo_person }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                        <br>
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item">Контрагент: <b>{{ form.company }}</b></li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">ФИО Водителя: <b>{{ form.name }}</b></li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">Маршрут: <b>{{ form.route }}</b></li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">Номер автомобиля: <b>{{ form.state_number }}</b></li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">Номер телефон: <b>0{{ form.phone }}</b></li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">Договор до: <b>{{ form.paid_until }}</b></li>
                            </ul>
                        <br>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block btn-mob"><i class="far fa-save"></i> Сохранить</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ bus.photo_license.url }}" alt="">
                                {{ form.photo_license }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ bus.photo_car_pass.url }}" alt="">
                                {{ form.photo_car_pass }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ bus.photo_front.url }}" alt="">
                                {{ form.photo_front }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ bus.photo_back.url }}" alt="">
                                {{ form.photo_back }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ bus.photo_route.url }}" alt="">
                                {{ form.photo_route }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Buses(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    route = models.IntegerField()
    phone = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    paid_until = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    photo_person = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', default='avatar.jpg')
    photo_front = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', default='carcas.png')
    photo_back = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', default='carcas.png')
    photo_car_pass = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', default='carcas.png')
    photo_license = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', default='carcas.png')
    photo_route = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', default='carcas.png')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


    urlpatterns = [
        path('', include('buses.urls')),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]   + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Все потому что ты сохраняешь ItemForm которая в свою очередь создает модель. А чтобы изменять модель, нужно работать с моделью item которую ты получаешь с помощью метода `get_object_or_404`

Comment: @E1mir спасибо что ответили на вопрос, но ответ я не понял)) что мне нужно поменять? во вьюхе

Comment: Для начала попробовать добавить поле id. У тебя форма инициализируется 2 раза. При чем второй раз form = ItemForm(request.POST, request.FILES). В request.POST не приходит id объекта. Соответственно нужно его добавить в initial или в POST, чтобы форма понимала, что работает с существующим объектом. Конечно, предполагаю, что работаешь с ModelForm

Comment: @KamoPetrosyan обьязательно ли добавлять id, мне нужно  request.FILES куда то добавить, что бы картинку поменять, а тексты без него и без второго itemform работает, как достичь цель?

Comment: Если у объекта нет id, ORM создает новый

Comment: @KamoPetrosyan как мне ему дать id?

Comment: item = get_object_or_404(Buses, id=id)
post_values = request.POST.copy()
post_values.update({'id': item.pk})
form = ItemForm(post_values, request.FILES)

Comment: @KamoPetrosyan Добрый день, спасибо за ответ, НО не получилось по вашему коду достичь результата, я немного подругому сделал но все равно не ах ти, теперь сохраняет текущий обьект, но не выводит заполненые поля, кроме картинок, с картинками все ок, если у вас есть решение то напишите в виде ответа , спасибо.